# Generate a uniform distribution of orientations

Tags: uniform-distribution

I am rendering images of a 3D object and am trying to generate a uniform distribution of orientations for this object. I am unsure of how to do this, and considerations that are necessary to take into account.

1. Is a uniform distribution of orientations equivalent to a uniform distribution of rotations as apparent to a rendering camera? That is, if I generate uniform orientations, will it look uniform to the camera?
2. How do I generate a uniform distribution of orientations? Is it possible to generate uniform points on a `d-sphere` to get a set of rotations? If so, would this mean generating points on a 3D sphere or a 4D hypersphere?

Comment: What precisely do you mean by "poses"?

Comment: I've edited the question to be more precise

Comment: Uniform distribution of *rotations* or instead *orientations* (poses)?

Comment: This is the 3D version of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability) Also see https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=bertrand%20paradox

Answer (score 1):

One good way to generate a uniformly distributed point on the unit sphere in $\mathbb R^n$ is to take $(Z_1,\ldots,Z_n)$ independent with standard normal distribution, and
divide by the norm $\sqrt{Z_1^2 + \ldots + Z_n^2}$.  To get a uniformly distributed  orthogonal $n \times n$ matrix, take $n^2$ independent standard normal $Z_{ij}$ and orthonormalize by Gram-Schmidt.

Answer (score 0):

Simple in *Mathematica*:

```
Graphics3D[
   {Opacity[0.5], Yellow, Sphere[], 
    Black, PointSize[0.02], 
    Point /@ SpherePoints[200]}]
```

[image: Sphere with uniform points]

Comment: I'm not sure this answers my question. Are you saying that a 3D sphere of uniformly distributed points is equivalent to a uniform distribution of apparent rotations?

Comment: Well, until you define "uniform distribution of apparent rotations," I guess this is all we can assume.  Oh... and for each of the vectors defied by a point, rotate uniformly around the $2 \pi$ radians.

Comment: I apologize, I believe I wasn't using the correct term for what I was intending to say. I think it would be more correct to say orientation (as your comment to my question notes) rather than rotation or apparent rotation. I have edited my question. Given that I am looking for uniform orientations, is your answer the same?